# Joomla Mailer won't send a second Email

Tags: php, jmail

I'm currently working on a big Joomla website created by a professional company, my job is to take some of the forms and update them. I've been using the Joomla Doc most of the time, but I'm still learning to use the framework.

In the custom subscription form, I need to send two E-Mails, one for the account activation link (Which is sent during the user creation process) and the other for an overview of the user transaction (Which is also sent to the administrator). However, the system only sends one or the other, not both.

The guy who wrote the code before me cut those two mail in two function that would need a complete code overhaul to fuse, so I can't do anything about it since I'm an intern. Still, here's the important part of both methods.

First, the one during the user creation process

```
// Compile the notification mail values.
    $data = $user->getProperties();
    $data['fromname'] = $config->get('fromname');
    $data['mailfrom'] = $config->get('mailfrom');
    $data['sitename'] = $config->get('sitename');
    $data['siteurl'] = JUri::root();
    // Set the link to confirm the user email.
    $uri = JURI::getInstance();
    $base = $uri->toString(array('scheme', 'user', 'pass', 'host', 'port'));
    $data['activate'] = $base . JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&task=registration.activate&token=' . $data['activation'],
                    false);
    $emailSubject = JText::sprintf(
                    'COM_USERS_EMAIL_ACCOUNT_DETAILS',
                    $data['name'],
                    $data['sitename']
    );
    $emailBody = JText::sprintf(
                    'COM_USERS_EMAIL_REGISTERED_WITH_ADMIN_ACTIVATION_BODY',
                    $data['name'],
                    $data['sitename'],
                    $data['siteurl'] . 'index.php?option=com_users&task=registration.activate&token=' . $data['activation'],
                    $data['siteurl'],
                    $data['username'],
                    $data['password_clear']
    );
    // Send the registration email.
    JFactory::getMailer()->sendMail($data['mailfrom'],
            $data['fromname'],
            $data['email'],
            $emailSubject,
            $emailBody);
```

And here's the one for the transaction :

```
    $config = JFactory::getConfig();
    $sender = array( 
    $config->getValue('config.mailfrom'),
    $config->getValue('config.fromname'));
    $to = $values['facture_email'];
    $subject = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ' . $values['nouveau'];
    $mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
    $mailer->setSender($sender);
    $mailer->addRecipient($to);
    $mailer->addBCC(array($from, 'xxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.xxxxxx'));
    $mailer->setSubject($subject);
    $mailer->isHTML(true);
    $mailer->Encoding = 'base64';
    $mailer->setBody($message);
    if (isset($values['carte']) && $values['carte'] != '')
    {
        $mailer->addAttachment(JPATH_COMPONENT . DS . 'assets' . DS . 'php' . DS . 'files' . DS . $values['carte']);
    }
    $send = $mailer->Send();
```

I checked the code 10 times and there is nothing in there that would prevent the second email to be sent if the first was... I suppose it's probably because I call getMailer() twice in the same event, but there is nothing in the joomla doc that would confirm this.

Thanks

Comment: In your Joomla setup what do you have in your global mail settings?

Comment: Did you try to send out the transaction mail with the same way which is used on the user creation process?

Comment: @cppl I've setup my email settings for my bluehost account, with SMTP and SSL security.

Comment: @Laoneo I tried both methods, still the same problem, only the user creation mail is sent.

Comment: Do it the hard way and an var_dump($send);die; after you sent out the second mail.

Comment: I found one of the errors. It's pretty dumb, I needed to set the $mailer->SMTPDebug to false for the mail to send. I seems that if you debug your mailer once, you need to set it to false for it to still work, removing the line won't work. I also used @Laoneo var_dump($send);die;, it sends both mails, but then my "thank you" page is replaced by a blank page with bool(true) in it.

Comment: I don't know what I did right, but once I removed the var_dump, it works like a charm. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

What joomla version you are using?

In older version of joomla the later part of the code (second chunk) might not work.

And again for the code,

```
$mailer->addAttachment(JPATH_COMPONENT . DS . 'assets' . DS . 'php' . DS . 'files' . DS . $values['carte']);
```

Try to use

```
$mailer->addAttachment(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/assets/php/files/'.$values['carte']);
```

and make sure the path eg: joomla/components/com_extend/assets/php/files/file_name exists (check in a if condition before attaching it)